# DuckDB for reading multiple parquet files on s3

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, duckdb

I am trying to use DuckDB with the HTTPFS extension to query around 1000 parquet files with the same schema from an s3 bucket with a similar key.

When I query a single file with duckdb I'm able to get the table

```
import duckdb
import pandas as pd

cursor = duckdb.connect()

df = cursor.execute(f"""
                        INSTALL httpfs;
                        LOAD httpfs;
                        SET s3_region='{s3_region}';
                        SET s3_access_key_id='{access_key_id}';
                        SET s3_secret_access_key='{secret_access_key}';
                        
                        SELECT *
                            FROM parquet_scan(['s3:://bucket/folder/fname.parquet'],
                                               FILENAME = 1);
                        """).df()
```

However, when I use file globbing, as explained by the docs (https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs), I get a `duckdb.Error: Invalid Error: HTTP GET error`, which is a HTTP 403 (Access Denied).

```
SELECT *
    FROM parquet_scan(['s3:://bucket/folder/*.parquet'],
                                               FILENAME = 1);
```

I thought this was just an AWS IAM permissions issue, but I've given list and read access to the entire bucket, so as far as I know, it isn't that.

What is causing this error?

Comment: One odd thing is I used boto3 to do list objects with the same access keys as the query, and I was able to get the data. I guess a quick hack would be just to use the output from boto3 list objects and concat the s3 uri's to pass to parquet_scan in the duckDB query. Not ideal, but doable.

Comment: Have you tried something like ```SELECT * FROM parquet_scan('s3://bucket/folder/*.parquet',
FILENAME = 1);```

Comment: If you mean without the brackets, yes. Doesn't work I'm afraid. Maybe glob matching isn't supported in parquet_scan only read_parquet?

Comment: When configured with the same access key, does `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder/` get the 403? If so, please show the IAM statement containing the s3:ListBucket action.

Comment: Have you tried setting `s3_session_token` ?

Comment: I did not, but that appears to fix it. It is weird that I could access the s3 bucket when I was just scanning one parquet, but I needed the session_token when using glob. Does this mean we need to create a session token anytime we want to query s3? That seems a bit much when you are just doing dev work on your own machine with your personal IAM credentials. I had a similar problem with HTTPFS calls in duckdb before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74789412/aws-role-vs-iam-credential-in-duckdb-httpfs-call

Answer (score 0):

Here are the tests that we run in CI/CD to test the S3 globbing. I don't see any issues with your syntax, so maybe it is a configuration or access issue of some kind?

https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/blob/4a24d71edecc7c0018eb3860d2e104cfe90462b6/test/sql/copy/parquet/parquet_glob_s3.test

Answer (score 0):

I was running in to the same issue. Session tokens worked for me. Set the following in the query instead of `key_id` and secret key.

```
SET s3_session_token='{aws_session_token}';
```