# AWS role vs iam credential in duckdb HTTPFS call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, duckdb

I am pretty baffled and I don't know what is going on with this one.

I'm using DuckDB to query parquet files in an s3 bucket.

```
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

query = """
    INSTALL httpfs;
    LOAD httpfs;
    SET s3_region='us-west-2';
    SET s3_access_key_id='key';
    SET s3_secret_access_key='secret';
    SELECT 
        FROM read_parquet('s3://bucket/folder/file.parquet') 

cursor = duckdb.connect()

cursor.execute(query).df()
```

I have an IAM user with admin access. I am able to query this parquet file with programatic access keys. I also have a role that I want to use in an application that I have also given admin access just for testing purposes.

When I assume the role and create temporary credentials and input those into the code above

```
export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" \
$(aws sts assume-role \
--role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/<role-name> \
--role-session-name test-session \
--query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" \
--output text))
```

I get the error

> duckdb.Error: Invalid Error: Unable to connect to URL
> "s3://bucket/folder/file.parquet": 403 (Forbidden)

However, when I use my IAM user, I am able to access this s3 object and query the data just fine. Is there something I am missing about the difference between roles and IAM users?

If it helps, what I am trying to do is create a role for a lambda function and then access the environmental variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` with `os.getenviron()` in the code above. I believe if I can get the role working by writing in the temporary credentials it should work when I use `os.getenv()` in the lambda function.

Comment: Another weird thing is I can assume the role with AWS cli and copy the file using those same credentials in the cli. ```aws s3 cp s3://bucket/folder/file.parquet .```

Comment: The official documentation explicitly says that Temp session credentials are not supported. More details at https://motherduck.com/docs/authenticating-to-s3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar issue, after also setting the `s3_session_token` via `SET s3_session_token='sessiontoken';` it worked. Also, be aware that S3 is not a global service, which means that you need to make sure to set the correct `s3_region`.

The code would be changed to

```
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

query = """
    INSTALL httpfs;
    LOAD httpfs;
    SET s3_region='us-west-2';
    SET s3_access_key_id='key';
    SET s3_secret_access_key='secret';
    SET s3_session_token='session-token';
    SELECT 
        FROM read_parquet('s3://bucket/folder/file.parquet') 

cursor = duckdb.connect()

cursor.execute(query).df()
```

Comment: wow that worked! Thanks so much. Why does it need a session token and temporary creds though?

Comment: I don't know, it was just trial & error in my case, as I had the same problem as you @ASimpleProgrammer

Comment: Same for me, thanks. This should be added to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers worn't help you, you might want to try **setting another S3_region**.

I got the same error message `Error: Invalid Error: IO Error: Unable to connect to URL "s3://elsa-data-lake/transformed/20230228_041047_00038_yihfd_00629123-f824-4a31-ba70-e341d4028a3b.parquet": 400 (Bad Request)`  but with different underlying problem. I set the wrong S3 region, thinking that S3 is a global service. I was using `SET s3_region='us-east-1'` because that is where our SSO service is set up, but I needed to specify the region where the file is stored on S3. So if I use `SET s3_region='eu-west-1` everything works!

Here is a screenshot from the S3 console that shows that my file was stored in "EU (Ireland) eu-west-1".
[image]